# Extract CSS Style From String in JAVA

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, regex

I have a string in  Java not escaped which contains CSS, JavaScript and HTML.

I need to extract all the CSS from this string, so basically I need to search for everything that start for `<style` and finish for `</style>` and everything that start for `<link` and finish for `>`

Any suggestions?

Comment: So basically you need a HTML parser.

Comment: I need to retrieve all the CSS because I want inject it in the HEAD tag instead the BODY

Comment: Yeah like Qtax said, a HTML parser could help you easily find the CSS. A Java HTML parser I've used before which uses jQuery like selectors, which I find convenient, can be found here: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Do you need to do this in JavaScript or Java?

Answer (score 2):

The regex might look something like this.
`String result = searchText.replaceAll("<style>([^<]*)</style>", "$1");`
this should change the text to whats inside the tag, just modify it slightly for the  tag